# I want to add dictionary inside another dictionary with same key names for multiple person data

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import json

data={}
mdata={}

count=1
data['label'] ='person1'
data['confidence']='60'
mdata[count]=data
print(mdata)

data['label'] ='person2'
data['confidence']='50'
mdata[count+1]=data
print(mdata)

data['label'] ='person3'
data['confidence']='40'
mdata[count+2]=data

print(mdata)



Actual Output:
{1: {'label': 'person1', 'confidence': '60'}}
{1: {'label': 'person2', 'confidence': '50'}, 2: {'label': 'person2', 'confidence': '50'}}
{1: {'label': 'person3', 'confidence': '40'}, 2: {'label': 'person3', 'confidence': '40'}, 3: {'label': 'person3', 'confidence': '40'}}

Expected Output:
{1: {'label': 'person1', 'confidence': '60'}}
{1: {'label': 'person1', 'confidence': '60'}, 2: {'label': 'person2', 'confidence': '50'}}
{1: {'label': 'person1', 'confidence': '60'}, 2: {'label': 'person2', 'confidence': '50'}, 3: {'label': 'person3', 'confidence': '40'}}
```

I want to add dictionary inside a dictionary so that i can have multiple record as shown below. I have two record as shown above after creating each dict and adding new values to pervious dictionary i want to added it with new key values in mdata dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You've only created one `data` dictionary and used it over and over, so of course `mdata` contains it three times. How could it know you want three different dictionaries? Set `data = {}` each time to create a fresh dictionary.

[Here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=data%3D%7B%7D%0Amdata%3D%7B%7D%0A%0Acount%3D1%0Adata%5B'label'%5D%20%3D'person1'%0Adata%5B'confidence'%5D%3D'60'%0Amdata%5Bcount%5D%3Ddata%0Aprint%28mdata%29%0A%0Adata%5B'label'%5D%20%3D'person2'%0Adata%5B'confidence'%5D%3D'50'%0Amdata%5Bcount%2B1%5D%3Ddata%0Aprint%28mdata%29%0A%0Adata%5B'label'%5D%20%3D'person3'%0Adata%5B'confidence'%5D%3D'40'%0Amdata%5Bcount%2B2%5D%3Ddata%0A%0Aprint%28mdata%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=15&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) is a visualisation of your code. Click '<< First' and then 'Forward >' a bunch of times to step through it.

Comment: Thanks You Cleared my dont and solved my problem.